# If i change projects, can I pick up where I left off?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I'm about halfway through a long research project, and still have 5 days left before it's finished. A new project just came up that only takes two days and is a priority project. If I switch to this project will I be able to pick up the old one where I left off?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, you can. You'll pick up where you left off. I'm not entirely sure you keep all of your progress, but a project that was mostly finished will still be mostly finished.

What's more, when you change research projects, if the project required special resources (a corpse or a particular object) then you'll get them back when you change projects, and they will be re-consumed when you resume the project.

Comment: This getting back feature 'could' be considered an exploit. If your starved for materials (market much did you?) you could use a limited amount of supply's and change research before its complete to keep the labs working.
While not completing this prevents downtime due to lack of materials so you can collect more. However if you have a shortage of materials... you do something wrong. Don't sell so much or dont grenade away all your fragments that much :P

Comment: I'm not a fan of labeling this kind of thing an exploit. It's not as if you can escape paying the material cost. And anyone who keeps up with their interrogations will have such fast research in the late game that the materials (not the research time) are the scarce resource.

Comment: Also, if you start work on a tech and get it partway complete, then interrogate an alien that applies a research credit to that tech, then when you resume researching it, the number of research points (scientist days) required is now half of the ORIGINAL amount. Eg) 10 scientists work 5 days on Beam Weapons (50 of 120RP), then you stop and interrogate a Sectoid. Upon resuming Beam Weapons, you now have 50 of 60RP completed and it will only take 1 more day to finish.